# use directory is not working in laravel-5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

the problem is quite simple the 
"(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'app\user' not found"

however i include use app/user in my controller file but still it happen here is my code...

```html
class userController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data = user::all();
        return view('user.index',compact('data'));
    }
```

Comment: what is your user model name ?

Comment: the model name is user

Comment: and the entity name in database is users

Comment: i have created a table with name users and then i create a model that is user then i include it with "use app\user" and use it on my function but it throws me an arror.

Answer (score 0):

type use `App\User;` take note of the capital letter A and capital letter U.